# o programa nao le os dados que estao no ficheiro de texto

Tags: python, sqlite3

O ficheiro de texto chuva.txt contem resultados de analises de pH a amostras de agua da chuva. Cada uma das linhas tem (separados por “;”)
a data do inicio da recolha da amostra (na forma AAAA-MM-DD), a duracao da recolha (em horas), a identificacao do local (uma sequencia com quatro caracteres), o ponto de amostragem do local (um numero entre 1 e 8) e o valor de pH medido.

Estou a tentar fazer uma funcao que insere os dados do ficheiro chuva.txt na tabela Amostras da base de dados agua.db. A funcao deve ler a informacao de chuva.txt e, por cada linha lida inserir esse registo na tabela Amostras.

```
def inserir_dadosBD(nomeBD,nomeFich,nomeTabela):
    bd = sql.connect(nomeBD, isolation_level = None)
    fich = open(nomeFich)
    nomeTabela = 'CREATE TABLE ' + nomeTabela + '(Data TEXT, Hora INTEGER, 
    Local VARCHAR(4), Ponto INTEGER, pH REAL, PRIMARY KEY(Data));'
    bd.execute(nomeTabela)
    for linha in fich.readlines():
        linha = linha.split(';')
        Data = linha[0]
        Hora = int(linha[1])
        Local = linha[2]
        Ponto = int(linha[3])
        pH = float(linha[4])
        com2 = 'INSERT INTO ' + nomeTabela + ' VALUES ('+ Data + ',' + 
        str(Hora) + ',' + Local + ',' + str(Ponto) + ',' + str(pH) + ');'
        print(com2)
        bd.execute(com2)    
    fich.close()
    bd.close()
```

Ao chamar `inserir_dadosBD('agua.db','chuva.txt','Amostras')` e

```
bd = sql.connect('agua.db',isolation_level = None)        
com = 'SELECT * FROM Amostras;'
res = bd.execute(com)
print(res.fetchall())
```

na lista de comandos aparece-me `[('Data', 'Hora', 'Local', 'Ponto', 'pH')]`
O que é que tenho de alterar no programa para ele passar a ler o que esta no ficheiro chuva.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando um arquivo texto como este:

```
2019-05-02; 5; ABCD; 1; 8
2019-05-03; 4; CDFD; 2; 6
2019-05-04; 3; DDFF; 2; 7
2019-05-05; 2; CBFG; 4; 8
2019-05-06; 1; HTYG; 5; 5
2019-05-07; 5; ABDD; 3; 2
```

Fiz algumas modificações na sua função, e ela ficou assim:

```
def inserir_dadosBD(nomeBD,nomeFich,nomeTabela):
    bd = sql.connect(nomeBD, isolation_level = None)
    fich = open(nomeFich)
    criaTabela = 'CREATE TABLE ' + nomeTabela + ' (Data TEXT, Hora INTEGER, Local VARCHAR(4), Ponto INTEGER, pH REAL, PRIMARY KEY(Data));'
    bd.execute(criaTabela)
    for linha in fich.readlines():
        linha = linha.split(';')
        Data = linha[0]
        Hora = int(linha[1])
        Local = linha[2]
        Ponto = int(linha[3])
        pH = float(linha[4])
        com2 = f"INSERT INTO {nomeTabela} VALUES ('{Data}' , {Hora} , '{Local}' , {Ponto} , {pH});"
        print(com2)
        bd.execute(com2)
    fich.close()
    bd.close()
```

Note:

- a mudança no nome da variável que cria a tabela. Você está sobrescrevendo o parâmetro.
- a mudança na formatação da variável que monta o insert. Se estiver usando Python < 3.6, pode usar o `format`:

`com2 = "INSERT INTO {nomeTabela} VALUES ('{Data}' , {Hora} , '{Local}' , {Ponto} , {pH});".format(nomeTabela=nomeTabela, Data=Data, Hora=Hora, Local=Local, Ponto=Ponto, pH=pH)`

Comment: Obrigado , enganei-me a passar: no meu programa as ultimas 2 linhas estao dentro da funcao. Mas porque é que preciso de acrescentar bd.commit() ? Nunca ouvi falar desse comando em sqlite3. E ja acrescentei ao codigo o bd.commit apos o bd.execute(com2) e continua a aparecer apenas  [('Data', 'Hora', 'Local', 'Ponto', 'pH')]...

Comment: Como você está usando o parâmetro isolation_level=None, está configurado o commit automático.

Comment: Obrigado mas nao percebi porque é que o "f" aparece nesta parte com2 = f"INSERT INTO {nomeTabela} VALUES ('{Data}' , {Hora} , '{Local}' , {Ponto} , {pH});" ? E porque é que meteste print(com2) ? Nao basta fazer bd.execute(com2)?

Comment: É uma novidade a partir da versão 3.6 do Python, chamada f-strings, para formatação de strings.

Comment: mas porque é que usaste print(com2) e bd.execute(com2)?

Comment: reproduzi exatamente o que estava no seu código. só consertei o que estava errado... para a funcionalidade o print é desnecessário.

Comment: ok obrigado, tambem concordo que nao devia de estar la o print (ja que nao altera nada)